# Spring Security SAML - Two host names issue

Tags: spring-saml

Our product uses two host names, one public (e.g. https://my-company.com:443) and private one for internal uses (https://localhost:443).
We manage to authenticate with the IDP using the public URL but when we try to load a resource after the login that try to use the private URL (localhost) we are getting this exception:

```
[02 May 2016 20:08:26,558] - SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: localhost
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name:
localhost
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

Note: we use the MetadataGenerator to create the SP metadata.

Answer (score 0):

At the end it wasn't spring security issue.

I managed to fix it by pointing the public domain to the localhost in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Hi resolve your company private ip  your etc/hosts file and access the url https://localhost:443/